# Is there still no IE onboard Windows 7 in Europe?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

This article is of  12 June 2009:
http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/8096701.stm

Is this still true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, and it has actually never been true. By the time Windows 7 was RTM, this issue was resolved. "Windows 7 E" (how it was called) has never been released.

See [this](http://microsoftontheissues.com/cs/blogs/mscorp/archive/2009/07/31/windows-7-and-browser-choice-in-europe.aspx) for the official explanation from Microsoft:

> One reason we decided not to ship
>   Windows 7 E is concerns raised by
>   computer manufacturers and partners.
>   Several worried about the complexity
>   of changing the version of Windows
>   that we ship in Europe if our ballot
>   screen proposal is ultimately accepted
>   by the Commission and we stop selling
>   Windows 7 E. Computer manufacturers
>   and our partners also warned that
>   introducing Windows 7 E, only to later
>   replace it with a version of Windows 7
>   that includes IE, could confuse
>   consumers about what version of
>   Windows to buy with their PCs.
>
> The Commission also previously
>   expressed concerns about Windows 7 E.
>   In a statement the day after I
>   outlined our plans for Windows 7 E,
>   the Commission clarified that it
>   believes “consumers should be offered
>   a choice of browser, not that Windows
>   should be supplied without a browser
>   at all.”
>
> We’re now confident that shipping
>   Windows 7 with IE in Europe—as we will
>   in the rest of the world—is the right
>   thing to do for our partners and for
>   our customers. We also feel encouraged
>   in making this decision by the
>   positive reaction from so many
>   quarters to our ballot screen proposal
>   last week.